# How do we prove Dynkin's formula for the resolvent of a strong Markov process?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

In eq. (1.1) of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.02595.pdf#page=2) it is claimed that if $X$ is strongly Markov at a stopping time $\tau$, then it would follow from Dynkin's formula that $$(U_\alpha f)(x)=\operatorname E_x\left[\int_0^\tau e^{-\alpha t}f(X_t)\:{\rm d}t\right]+\operatorname E_x\left[e^{-\alpha\tau}(U_\alpha f)(X_\tau);\tau<\infty\right].\tag1$$ Above, $$U_\alpha:=\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha t}\kappa_t\:{\rm d}t,$$ where $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ is the transition semigroup of $X$. Iin operator theoretical sense, it is the resolvent of the generator $A$ of this semigroup.

> How do we show this?

Dynkin's formula yields $$\operatorname E_x\left[f(X_\tau)\right]=f(x)+\operatorname E_x\left[\int_0^\tau Af(X_s)\:{\rm d}s\right]\tag2.$$ How does $(1)$ follow from this?

Note that $$(\kappa_tf)(x)=\operatorname E_x\left[f(X_t)\right]\tag3$$ and $$f-e^{-\alpha t}\kappa_tf=(\lambda-A)\int_0^te^{-\lambda s}\kappa_sf\:{\rm d}s\tag4.$$

**EDIT**: Above we treat $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ as a contraction semigroup on a suitable Banach space $C\subseteq\{f:E\to\mathbb R\mid f\text{ is }\mathcal E\text{-measurable}\}$, where $(E,\mathcal E)$ is the measurable space $X$ takes its values in. The generator $A$ is then an unbounded linear operator given by $$Af:=\lim_{t\to0+}\frac{\kappa_t f-f}t$$ for every $f\in\mathcal D(A)$, where $\mathcal D(A)$ is preceisely the set of those $f$ for which $Af$ exists (i.e. the orbits $t\mapsto\kappa_tf$ are right-differentiable at $0$).

Comment: Another unclear close vote for a rather well-posed question!

Comment: To the OP: do you know how $\kappa$ and $A$ are related?

Comment: @Ilya Yes, sure. I've got a rather strong background in operator/semigroup theory and (at least for the moment) it's even easier for me to think about this problem from a functional analytical point-of-view. See my edit.

Comment: I don't think one needs $(2)$ here. Instead, can you show that for $\tau$ being fixed (deterministic) time for starters?

Comment: @Ilya I don't see how we could use $(2)$ either, but that's what I know as "Dynkin's formula" and the paper claims it would follow from that (and the strong Markov property). I'm also failing to prove it for deterministic times, which obviously would be a good starting point.

Comment: Try to take $\tau = s$ to be some deterministic time and write out $(1)$ using the definition of $U_\alpha$ and $(3)$. If I'm not mistaken, that's just decomposition of integral onto $[0,s]$ and $[s,\infty)$

Comment: @Ilya Hm, maybe I'm missing something, but $\tau=s$ in $(1)$ yields $$(U_\alpha f)(x)=\int_0^se^{-\alpha t}(\kappa_tf)(x)\:{\rm d}t+e^{-\alpha s}(\kappa_sU_\alpha f)(x)\tag5.$$

Comment: @Ilya Ah, we simply need to use $$\kappa_sU_\alpha f=\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha t}\kappa_{s+t}f\:{\rm d}t=e^{\alpha s}\int_s^\infty e^{-\alpha t}\kappa_tf\:{\rm d}t.$$ This indeed verifies $(1)$ for deterministic times. Do you know how we generalize this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135733/discussion-between-ilya-and-0xbadf00d).

Comment: @Ilya I'm sorry for my late response. I was on a business trip since Friday. I've posted something in the chat. Please check it out.